# How beneficial is Parallel Seq for executing sequence of statements?

Tags: scala, parallel-processing, par

I have a small program using List.par

```
val x = List(1,2,3,4,5).par.map(y => {
    Thread.sleep(2000)
    println(y)
    y + 1
})

println(x)
```

Output:

```
3
1
4
5
2
ParVector(2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
```

The numbers are getting printed in parallel however the return value is always keeping its order.

My aim is to execute a sequence of insert statements to SQL database in parallel.

Currently I am using ***for comprehension***.
I want to use ***ParSeq*** as number of statements are increasing.

But I am afraid whether it results in performance degradation. (If there is extra code in ***map*** implementation for preserving its order, this is a performance overhead).

Kindly suggest me how to do it.

Comment: If you want the best performances, you should probably look for SQL batch inserts rather than running each insertion in its own (short-lived) thread.

Comment: Yeah but unfortunately I can't go with batch insert as I am using same code for sql db in production and in memory db for testing.

Comment: @ShantiswarupTunga just sharing my opinion, if testing drives what you application can do, I would rethink how to test. Especially for db wrappers I came to the conclusion that the best thing is not to unit-test them, but rather run integration tests against a real db, and to simplify the process of testing for development I would recommend [**Testcontainers**](https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-scala).

Answer (score 6):

[Documentation](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/parallel-collections/overview.html) ("Semantics" section) explains that there are only two possible scenarios that might lead to out-of-order behaviour:

1. Side-effecting operations can lead to non-determinism
2. Non-associative operations lead to non-determinism

First one you have observed yourself with the `println` statements. Second one is easily testable by using a non-associative binary operation such as subtraction:

```
val list = (1 to 100).toList
val a = list.par.reduce(_ - _)

println(a)
```

Try running the above snippet a couple of times.

A list of integers can be mapped in parallel by a number of workers, because the elements don't depend on each other. Each worker can perform the operation in-place without affecting any other element. So even if it's perhaps not intuitive at first, such processing *does* benefit from the parallelization (but for an improvement to be noticeable you will probably need a larger number of elements).

However, that same list cannot be reduced in parallel with a non-associative operation, because the elements do depend on each other, and it makes a big difference whether you do:

> 1 - (2 - (3 - 4))

or

> ((1 - 2) - 3) - 4

This is why parallel processing of a collection usually supports `reduce` and `fold`, but not `foldLeft` and `foldRight`.

Comment: Preserving the order is not necessary for me as it is going to be insert operations. But if after the statements got executed , it is trying to re-arrange it to its original order then this is a performance overhead. 
My question is it good approach to go for ParSeq in stead of For Comprehension?

Comment: You can also suggest any good approach for executing a sequence of insert statement.

Comment: Don't worry about internal implementation, it's doing stuff in place. There's no reordering because there's no shuffling. Imagine a queue of 100 people waiting in some line. Another 100 approach in parallel, each newcomer gives one person from the queue 1 dollar and leaves. Everyone in the queue now has 1 dollar more than they had, and it all happened in parallel, and the order within the queue is preserved.

Comment: I can't comment on insert statements because it's a much bigger topic and I don't have all the details (plus to be honest it's a completely different question). But generally speaking, using `.par` should do the trick. And, given that talking to the DB is side-effectful, your results will most likely happen out of order anyway, so don't worry about the case of mapping the list.